# How to convert GMT to locale dateTime?

Tags: apex, datetime

I want to convert the GMT dateTime to locale dateTime as `System.now()`. But after converting the format when I am trying to convert that string into dateTime again it is giving me the GMT dateTime.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me, but my two possible interpretations are you want to format the current `Datetime` according to your locale, or you want to adjust the `System.now()` result to account for the local time zone.

If you just want a locale-specific formatted string to represent the current `Datetime`, use:

```
String formatted = Datetime.now().format();
```

If you are trying to get the current `Datetime` in the local time zone, you can use the following code:

```
Datetime now = Datetime.now();
Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(now);
Datetime local = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);
```

Comment: Or just `String formattedLocalTimeString = DateTime.now().format()`.

Comment: @sfdcfox They want it in the local time zone, no?

Comment: DateTime.format() always returns the value as local time.

Comment: `DateTime.valueOfGMT(String.valueOf(DateTime.now()))` is essentially the same as what you're doing by altering the offset. I just wish I knew this two years ago. Ah well.

Comment: Wow, didn't know those tidbits. Weird that `system.debug(Datetime.now())` does not represent the same moment in time as `system.debug(Datetime.now().format())`.

Comment: It does... the annoying part is that DateTime values always debug in GMT. You have to change it to a string to get local values.