# How can I convert a time value given in IST to GMT in apex?

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

I have the following information: Week Number, Week Day and Time in AM/PM as fields in an object. And, another field to indicate if these values are provided as per GMT or IST. 
In my apex code, I will check if these values are in GMT/IST. If provided in IST, I want to take these fields and calculate the corresponding GMT values.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please check this Post:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155393/how-to-convert-gmt-to-locale-datetime

Comment: Fiddling with timezones is not something I would volunteer for. Dates and times are tricky subjects. What is your motivation for doing this? What are you trying to build here? Salesforce automatically converts datetimes to the timezone of the user viewing the data, and stores datetimes as GMT in their back-end. What about this built-in solution doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This may help (a Util method in my lib)

```
//  ------------------------------------------------------------------
//  getDateTimeGmt  : Returns a datetime in GMT from a timezoneId, date and time object
//  ------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static Datetime getDateTimeGmt(String tzId, Date d, Time t) {
        DateTime    res;
        if (tzId == null || d == null || t == null) return res;
        Timezone    tz          = Timezone.getTimeZone(tzId);
        DateTime    dt          = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(d,t);
        Integer     offsetMs    = tz.getOffset(dt);                 // #ms offset from datetime in Tz to GMT
        Integer     offsetMins  = offsetMs / (1000 * 60);
        res = dt.addMinutes(-1 * offsetMins);

        return res;
    }
```

where `tzId` is [defined in this list](http://www.salesforceben.com/list-timezonesidkey-salesforce/). You would use `Asia/Kolkata`

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to construct the Time object from your Am/PM user input data